# Let B be the set of all strings of 0’s and 1’s.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let B be the set of all strings of 0’s and 1’s. A binary relation G is defined on B as follows: for
all s, $t \in B$, s G t$\iff $ the number of 0’s in s is greater than the number of 0’s in t. Determine
whether G is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive, or none of them. Justify your
answer

I have no idea how to do this. Please someone help

Comment: Do you know the definitions of these properties ? Do you know if the $<$ relations on the integers is reflexive ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start you off with reflexive to give you an idea. To prove $G$ is reflexive we need to show $\forall s \in B$ we have $s G s$. But since we defined our relation to be **strictly** greater than clearly the number of 0's in $s$ is not greater than the number of 0's in $s$.

If we think about the count of 0's in a string as a map from the alphabet 0,1 to $N$ then really this is equivalent to the $>$ operator properties.

Comment: why can't I get \N to give me natural numbers?

Comment: Use `\Bbb N` or `\mathbb N`.